# Restoring Expression Engine on localhost: how to set up connection to database

Tags: php, database

### It was missing files from site backup - error from the user.
Case solved.

I'm trying to restore Expression Engine v2 (very old version) site on localhost, but I can't find config file in which credentials of connection to database should be specified.

I installed EE v7 for a test and I found out that credentials are stored in "system\user\config\config.php", but it seems that file structure since v2 has been changed and I can't find any corresponding config file in EE v2.

In PHP files I've found following statements:

```
define('APPPATH', $system_path.'expressionengine/');
[...]
$this->config_path        = APPPATH.'config/config.php';
```

But there is no "expressionengine/config" folder in my site backup.
Could it be that site backup is somehow incomplete?
Though user said he made full backup of site and files.

Comment: Is it `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

The main config file for ExpressionEngine v2 is in `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` [according to the guide](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/general/system_configuration_overrides.html). You probably need to check `system/expressionengine/config/database.php` too. You can download v2.11.9 from [here](https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/releases/tag/2.10.1) and [go through the installation steps](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/installation/installation.html) to check where the database credentials are stored as it is closer to v2 than v7.

Also check [this very old tutorial video](https://youtu.be/_4YlHgT4Gdo?list=PL07271CFF71F8FF22&t=230) or [its full playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL07271CFF71F8FF22) I found on YouTube as it has more details of the EE v2 starting from installation procedures. You can also find more about ExpressionEngine v2 in the [docs for v2](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/index.html) - and check [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/general/system_configuration_overrides.html) specifically for `'System Configuration Overrides'` section.